# search string and excise beginning portion - Solaris

Tags: sed, awk, solaris

Another Solaris question.

This is my file.

```
/abc/123/gfh/hello/what/is/up <THIS WOULD BE WHERE A NEW LINE STARTS>
bhn/fda/fds/hello/the/sky/is/blue <THIS WOULD BE WHERE A NEW LINE STARTS>
...etc
```

I need to delete everything before "hello" include the forward slash "/" infront of it for everyline in the file...

I'm stuck -> I had used a sed -E command but Solaris doesn't recognize the "-E". sigh

Answer (score 1):

I think you can grep this:

```
grep -o hello.*
```

Answer (score 0):

This should delete everything up to the slash before "hello":

```
sed -e 's|^.*hello/|hello|' <inputfile >outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it:

sed -e 's/.*hello(.*)/hello\1/'

Answer (score 0):

@user4815162342: No need for "^" in the sed solution, ".*" would suffice.
Since there was an awk tag too, here's the equivalent awk solution:

```
awk '{sub(/.*hello\//,"hello")}1'
```